# Disable computed observable

Tags: knockout.js

I Have a problem were a computed observable is creating the notification chain from hell (Ordo n^2).

What I need todo is this

```
Disable computed observable
Do stuff
Enable observable and notify subscribers (View)
```

Found this but its over a year old,

http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/04/pausing-notifications-in-knockoutjs.html

I was hoping there is some build in solution for this by now?

edit: A fiddle showing the problem. http://jsfiddle.net/8mxBA/

its pretty close to the real sites code
Try to select all items with teh top checkbox it will only do two calls to the canSave computed, try to uncheck it, it will do n calls to the canSave computed, and since the canSave method itterates over the entire collection it could get slow.

Comment: Might need some more detail or a jsFiddle sample to provide better help, but the article above does still stand.  Additional techiniques that could help are the "throttle" extender: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/throttle-extender.html or take a look at Michael Best's deferred updates plugin: https://github.com/mbest/knockout-deferred-updates

Comment: I think that you can use the "pauseable" idea to make this work.  Here is an updated sample: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/8mxBA/2/

Comment: Ah, its built in now? You should update your knockmeout article, I cut and pasted that code from your article. Thanks for the update, thats gow I did it only I used the one from knockmeout article

Comment: Checked the code more closely now, smart, that could be made into a extender too.. thanks!

Comment: The version from the article wraps the functionality a bit nicer (the read function does not need to know that it is being pause flag). Just wanted to show that it can be done pretty easily with an observable flag that you can add as a sub-observable.  Extenders or augmenting `.fn` of the base types would be a good way to go now that those techniques are available since KO 2.0.

Comment: I know you asked for pausable, but it sounds like what you really want is a computed that doesn't update when rapid changes are being made to it. Have you seen the [throttle extender](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/throttle-extender.html)?

Answer (score 1):

Try the throttle option ('not the extender').

```
comp = ko.computed(function () {
    return stuff;
}, this, {throttle: 1});
```

I believe the throttle extender wraps the computed in an additional computed so is less efficient.

Comment: `comp = ko.computed(function () {
    return stuff;
}).extend({ throttle: 1 })` worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out, which is an update on the `throttle` extender: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/rateLimit-observable.html